How to filter the ac signal in a dc cooling fan circuit
The cooling fan in a vehicle is powered by a 12V battery. When the fan begins to work, in addition to the dc current, there is ac signals in the circuit, and the frequency of the ac current increases as the rotaion speed increas.
I want to filter this signal to reduce its flow to the battery, So I connected two 10000uF capacitors in parallel to the electronic fan. But the AC signal passing through the battery did not decrease.
Why is that? How could I decrease the ac signal caused by the motor rotation of cooling fan?
The cooling fan is a DC Brushless motor with a built-in controller.

read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/709023/do-batteries-have-capacitance

What's the motor type in the fan? Is it DC brushed motor? Or is it a DC Brushless motor with a built-in controller? Depending on that, different filters might be required

A simple low pass LC filter is the first thing that one might think of to reduce the supply current ripple in a circuit that draws current in pulses. Here is a model we can use to simulate such a circuit. The load is I1 and it consists of a square wave current source with 50% duty ratio and an average current of 1 A. I did not use a PI or T network because they don't add anything useful at this point in our analysis.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
One can find in many places on the internet that the cutoff frequency of an LC low pass filter is given by
$$f_{cutoff} = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$
Despite this formula appearing in many locations, in general the calculated frequency is not what one would usually consider a cutoff frequency. The cutoff frequency of a low pass filter, according to this answer, is the frequency at which the output is attenuated by 3 dB (actually closer to 3.0103) of its DC amplitude. Here is the frequency response of the the above circuit. The output is taken to be the current through the voltage supply on the left.

If we attempt to find the cutoff frequency using the formula given above, we find that it gives
$$f_{cutoff} = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}} = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{10^{-4}}} \approx 1.59 \text{kHz} $$
However consulting the actual frequency response, we see that this frequency does not correspond to 3 dB of attenuation, but actually to a peaking frequency. The formula above, which is found in numerous places, just plain doesn't work for what is here considered a cutoff frequency.
The 3 dB attenuation frequency for this circuit is actually given by the formula (as far as I know).
$$f_{cutoff} = \frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$
Using that formula we arrive at a cutoff frequency of
$$f_{cutoff} \approx {\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}} \times 1.59 \approx 1.554 \times 1.59 \approx 2.47 \text{kHz}$$
This agrees with our simulation quite well:

Now, according to the simulation, this LC filter will attenuate the 30 kHz current ripple by something in the vicinity of 50 dB. This sounds like a vast improvement. But there is something that should not escape our notice. The peak in the frequency response indicates that the filter we have will ring.
Here is an example of the simulated time domain output. Again, we are taking the output to be the current through the source voltage Vin.

The 30 kHz current ripple is not noticeable. However, in it's place we see a ringing at 1.59 kHz, the natural frequency of the LC low pass filter, the frequency of the "peaking".
To address this, we can add a resistor in parallel with L1 to dampen the ringing.

simulate this circuit
In this case, I chose a 1\$\Omega\$ resistor, because that is the value of \$\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$. The optimal choice will depend
The time domain response now looks like.

The ringing is essentially gone. There is some overshoot, but not much. However, the 30 kHz ripple from the load is now back. This is a trade off. Increasing the resistor value will lower the 30 kHz ripple, but will increase the 1.59 kHz ringing. In some cases, we may not care about the ringing. In the present case we have a fan, and if the load on the fan motor is constant, the ringing will soon dissipate. So perhaps a higher value resistor, or even no resistor at all, might be the optimal choice. In other cases, if the load current changes, we may want to lower the ringing, but also keep the ripple from the load low. Using more components than the one capacitor, one inductor and one resistor can help. I will not offer more complex solutions.
Note that in many cases, a combination component called a ferrite bead can be used. A ferrite bead not only acts somewhat like an inductor, but also like a resistor at higher frequencies and a capacitor at even higher frequencies. Choosing a ferrite bead which has a resistive impedance at the frequency of the load ripple current serves an essentially similar purpose to the RLC circuit above.
As a final note, in some cases, perhaps when there is severe current ripple, or to comply with EMI regulations, an active circuit may be used to smooth out the current ripple on the supply side.

What you need to filter those ripples is a Pi or a T filter (source of image):

A simple capacitor is not enough. You need to have an inductor in series to create a low-pass filter.
Choose the filter cut-off frequency according to the lowest ripple frequency (lower fan speed). You will end up with a bigger Inductor/Capacitor, but it will filter the higher frequencies too.
For the Pi filter, the cutoff frequency can be calculated this way (source):

For the T filter, please have a look at this answer.

Thanks for your response, whether the inductance affects the switch of the fan, because the inductor resists the change of current

Well, that would be the point of having the inductor. It will smoothen the current change and reduce the ripple. If you end up with very big inductors in the filter, then switching off the fan could create a spark (the motor is already a big inductor and does that anyway)..

How to choose the right inductors and capacitors for a Pi or T filter? The frequency to be filtered in my fan circuit is about 1 kHz.

I added the link to the calculation in the answer. For the Pi filter, if I calculated correctly, for 1KHz and 10000uF capacitors, the inductor would be 2.5mH.

I know that the formula that you give for the cutoff frequency is found in many places on the internet. Unfortunately, despite its widespread presence, it is wrong. See my answer for more details.

That seems about right. I wasn't sure why the parallel capacitor to the voltage source could make a difference (at least with an ideal voltage source). I'll keep the answer as the formula comes from the liked sources. I voted up your answer. The simulation results are a great help.

Assuming there is nothing else powered by the same wires as the fan, a common mode filter should be effective at reducing both differential mode and common mode noise.

https://ka7oei.blogspot.com/2012/12/reducing-switching-supply-racket-rf.html
(I am not endorsing anything in the source page, I just grabbed the image.)
Each capacitor should be a large value electrolytic plus a small ceramic type in parallel, in the 0.22 uF to 1.0 uF range.  Common mode chokes are available from most distributors.  Here are some at Digi-Key.
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/common-mode-chokes/839?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIAzAExxUUAMIhALGGABxwDsIAuoQAcALlBABlIQCcAlgDsA5iAC%2BhMHHaIQKSBhwFiZcFTDUYfQSMjipcxSvC0Km7bryESkcm25cNqtVwArIwsgWEILOwUXDwsXBRgZoTBcPQhIIFU7GxMGVT56WH0ME7Jway5gcz5SRlczBSlGY5NgewwMBDJ7JyBuTD0cGCxIAMU1f1UXDS5iUFwzLNUwVzpYFQwXGCLqhvbVEvszEFL6puzCYEJF%2BP0fuDjgeoX1eMXA-Q7D9Mw91T0YCeX2GgOYay2Vwi4GmnCawwocBgwK4A3qsxiGz6ql8mNy%2BWm-zxUzUB0I-yuzD%2BxXYnzx9HqzCh-3YdCptFWeLAAJyZK5v1JICox3qf2FxXMIGEogkMgUykIAFoDtAtFApABXfQech9XhKfVAA
Consider something like this:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kemet/SS30V-R100700/10321625

If the noise is coming from commutation (or perhaps also PWM chop used for car fans), a common-mode choke won't help, since the noise is differential.
